# how to remove something from a string

Tags: c++

so, I have an string right here

```
"test///"
```

and I want to remove

```
"///"
```

from that string

I have tried to use this

```
str.replace
```

but it didn't work.
so can someone help?

Comment: Please post your exact str.replace

Comment: What arguments did you pass to `str.replace`?

Comment: Do you want to remove the last three characters no matter what they are? Do you want to remove `///` if it appears anywhere in the string? A combination of both? Something else? Be specific.

Comment: `but it didn't work.` Create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

The question is very broad. But basically, you do not want to replace something in your string, but you want to remove or erase the trailing slashes.

There are so many solutions that it is not possible to show the right one.

But if you want to stick to "replace" in a flexible manner, you could use function `std::regex_replace`

You can define, what will be replaced with a `std::regex`, which will give you big flexibility.

Example:

```
std::string output = std::regex_replace(input, std::regex("///"), "");
```

As said, this is one of millions of possible solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following example code:

```
  string str1="test///";
  string str2 = str1.substr (0,str1.length()-3);
```

This will make a substring by removing the last three characters and store it in new string str2. However, you can change the number of characters to remove as per your need.

Comment: Although your code will work in the specific example shown, the OP *may* be looking for a more general method to remove a given sequence of characters (at an unknown location) from the string.